# How create react base component that I can extend?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to extend a component and override one method, but both of the below methods do not work.

```
    var Hello = React.createClass( {
        getName: function() { throw "This method not implemented" },
        render: function() {
            return <this.props.component.slug className='text'>
                {this.props.component.value}{this.getName()}
            </this.props.component.slug>;
        }
    });

    class HelloChild extends Hello {
        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
        }

        getName()
        {
          return "Child";
        }
    };
```

Second attempt:

```
    class Hello extends React.Component {
        getName() { throw "This method not implemented" }
        render() {
            return <this.props.component.slug className='text'>
                {this.props.component.value}{this.getName()}
            </this.props.component.slug>;
        }
    };

    class HelloChild extends Hello {
        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
        }

        getName()
        {
          return "Child";
        }
    };
```

When I try to render the HelloChild, it throws the error:

```
Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child
(found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of 
children, use an array instead or wrap the object using 
createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method
of `bound `.
```

How do I extend it and only override one method?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you fail, please check the error log again, I think the problem is `this.props.component.value` is an object, not a string or array.

Comment: how about add `this.getName  = this.getName.bind(this) ` in the constructor function of Hello Component.